# Auto_increment custom Primary Key in Peewee model

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I want a primary key `id` field to be `Bigint`

```
class Tweets(Model):
    id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

But it needs to be auto_incremented and I can't find a way in the Peewee docs.
Please suggest if it's possible.

Update: I'm using MySql db.

Answer (score 4):

Peewee automatically generates an integer `id` column serving as primary key, having the auto_increment property. This is true for any table you create with Peewee.

It is very likely that `IntegerField` is enough for your needs; `BigIntegerField` is very rarely useful. Will you really need numbers bigger than 2147483647? Will you insert more than two billion rows?

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: It would be useful for a slightly large scale application. 2147483647 is not a very big number for computer.

Comment: Depends on the application. But you are right in this particular case, as I guess tweets are of this order of magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

Peewee, as of 3.1, includes a BigAutoField which is an auto-incrementing integer field using 64-bit integer storage. Should do the trick:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#BigAutoField

Comment: Thanks ! This is the up to date answer. Nice and clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most convenience answer is by using [SQL constraints](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#indexes-and-constraints):

```py
import peewee

class MyModel(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True,
            constraints=[peewee.SQL('AUTO_INCREMENT')])
```

Comment: the code snippet above works pretty well with peewee==2.10.1

Answer (score 1):

**Looks like this should help.**

After creating table, do:

```
db.register_fields({'primary_key': 'BIGINT AUTOINCREMENT'})
```

After that when you say

```
class Tweets(Model):
    id = PrimaryKey()
    ...
    class Meta():
        db = db
```

Then in mysql that field will appear as BigInt with auto increment

Comment: ps: may be you also should replace id with pk .. not sure for that.